# Java 8 Streams - Sort nested lists hierarchically

Tags: java, sorting, java-8, java-stream

Given the following example, I would like a stream function that sorts the list and also the nested list

```
class Foo {
    public int sort;
    public List<Bar> bars;
    public Foo(int sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }

}

class Bar {
    public int sort;

    public Bar(int sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }
}

@Test
public void testSortering() {
    Foo foo = new Foo(1);
    Foo foo2 = new Foo(2);
    Bar bar = new Bar(1);
    Bar bar2 = new Bar(2);
    foo.bars = Arrays.asList(bar2, bar);
    foo2.bars = Arrays.asList(bar2, bar);

    List<Foo> foos = Arrays.asList(foo2, foo);

    //I would like to iterate foos and return a new foos sorted, and with bars sorted, so that this goes green

    assertEquals(1, foos.get(0).sort);
    assertEquals(1, foos.get(0).bars.get(0).sort);
    assertEquals(2, foos.get(0).bars.get(1).sort);
    assertEquals(2, foos.get(1).sort);
    assertEquals(1, foos.get(1).bars.get(0).sort);
    assertEquals(2, foos.get(1).bars.get(1).sort);

}
```

I have tried this:

```
List<List<Bar>> foosSorted = foos.stream()
        .sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.sort, o2.sort))
        .map(f -> f.bars.stream().sorted((o1, o2) -> Integer.compare(o1.sort, o2.sort)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but this returns Bar, whilst I want a list of Foo

Comment: Do you want it to modify the existing `Foo` objects (that wouldn't be terribly functional...) or create new `Foo` objects with a sorted list of `Bar` objects?

Comment: You should first think about what you actually want to do. Sort the list contained in `Foo.bars` in-place or create new instances of `Foo`. In the former case, just call `List.sort` on these lists. In the latter case, you have to construct new `Foo` instances in your `map` operation.

Comment: I would like a new list with sorted foos and sorted bars

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<Foo> foosSort = foos.stream()
                     .sorted((o1, o2) -> (o1.sort - o2.sort))
                     .map(f -> {
                          List<Bar> bars = f.bars.stream()
                            .sorted((o1, o2) -> (o1.sort- o2.sort))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                          f.bars = bars;
                          return f;
                     })
                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I will choose this as the best answer since it doesn't need to create a new Foo object and constructor, plus since you are a new user :)

Comment: Instead of creating a `Bar` Stream and a new collection you can simply call `Collections.sort`.

Comment: @zeroflagL: only if you know that the list is mutable. In this case, it’s even easier as you can call `sort` on the list directly.

Comment: @Holger Right. I often forget that Java 8 brought new methods to collections as well. Damned be those default methods ;)

Answer (score 4):

The following will sort the `foos` and the `bars` for each `foo`, but since the `peek` operation is mutating `f`, this will have unexpected behaviour if parallelism is involved.

```
List<Foo> foosSorted = foos.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.sort))
           .peek(f -> {
                f.bars = f.bars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.sort)).collect(Collectors.toList());
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What I suggest is for you to add a constructor of `Foo` taking `sort` and `bars` and use `map` instead of `peek`. This way, we are not mutating any `Foo` object, so this can be run in parallel without trouble.

```
List<Foo> foosSorted = foos.stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.sort))
            .map(f -> {
                return new Foo(f.sort, f.bars.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(o -> o.sort)).collect(Collectors.toList()));
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

with:

```
class Foo {
    public int sort;
    public List<Bar> bars;
    public Foo(int sort) {
        this.sort = sort;
    }
    public Foo(int sort, List<Bar> bars) {
        this.sort = sort;
        this.bars = new ArrayList<>(bars);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks. I had it almost. I just needed to create a new foo in my map operation. Thanks!

Comment: You don’t need the curly braces, neither in `.peek(f -> { f.bars = expression; })`, which can be simply written as `.peek(f -> f.bars = expression)`, nor in `.map(f -> { return expression; })`, which can be simply written as `.map(f -> expression)`…