# how to sort nested lists in java

Tags: java, sorting, collections, java-8

I have a json like below :

```
{ 
  "Student": [
    {  
      "name":"5",
      "Roll No":12345,
      "Subjects":[  
        {  
           "subjectCode":"Mat"
        },
        {  
           "subjectCode":"Sci"
        }
      ]
    } 
  ]
}
```

I want to sort list of subjects within each student and then sorting student objects with roll no.Can it be done with java8 in single line.

I am using below code :

```
list.forEach(studentObj -> {
    studentObj.getSubjects()
      .sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Subject:: getSubjectCode)));
  });
```

then sorting the outside object

```
  list.sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Student:: getRollNo)));
```

Comment: `Can it be done with java8 in single line?` Yes probably, give it a try.

Comment: Technically every program can be written in single line.

Comment: Did you manage to map the JSON to an Object?

Comment: @Stultuske i have writtern the code above

Comment: Ok, I assume this works as expected, and you'd just like to merge these 2 lines into one?

Comment: @lkamal we can use ObjectMapper for that after coverting json to string

Comment: @hulk ...absolutley and people here are just downvoting my question

Comment: @AnujKumarSoni we downvoted because your question was not clear and was showing no effort. Note that we all upvoted once you added your code.

Comment: @AnujKumarSoni in that case, I think [Michał's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54107172/2513200) should be what you are looking for. It has the advantage of not changing the original list or the Students within that, but creates a new list of new students. I think your code is fine as it is, however, if it is OK to modify the input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 Streams - Sort nested lists hierarchically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32944984/java-8-streams-sort-nested-lists-hierarchically)

Answer (score 5):

If you were to implement the [Comparable interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) with your 2 classes `Student` and `Subject` you could make it really nice and short because you can use the [Comparator.naturalOrder()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#naturalOrder--) static factory method

Also it allows you to change the way you want to define how `Subjects` or `Students` get ordered by simply changing their `compareTo` method

**Student**

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    String name;
    int rollNo;
    List<Subject> subjects = new ArrayList<>();

    // GETTERS/SETTERS

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student student) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getRollNo(), student.getRollNo());
    }

}
```

**Subject**

```
class Subject implements Comparable<Subject> {
    String subjectCode;

    // GETTERS/SETTERS

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Subject subject) {
        return this.getSubjectCode().compareTo(subject.getSubjectCode());
    }

}
```

**And then**

```
// static import to make code lighter
import static java.util.Comparator.*;

// sort Students list, then sort Subjects list in each Student
list.sort(nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
list.forEach(s -> { if (s != null) {
   s.getSubjects().sort(nullsLast(naturalOrder())); 
}});
```

**One liner version** if you really need it

```
List<Student> sortedList = list.stream()
    .map(s -> {
        if (s != null) {
            s.getSubjects().sort(nullsLast(naturalOrder()));
        }
        return s;
    }).sorted(nullsLast(naturalOrder()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I liked this approach as it has a flavor of core concept alongwith java8 functionality

Comment: @AnujKumarSoni Always consider implementing Comparable when you need your objects to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

After parsing it to object you could write something like below:

```
List<Student> sorted = students.stream()
            .map(f -> new Student(f.getId(), f.getSubjects().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Subject::getSubjectCode)).collect(Collectors.toList())))
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Student::getRollNo))
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
```

Comment: This is just an idea of dealing with such problems, not production ready solution.

Comment: Nice idea. The only problem with the solution is that `map`ping would now require a constructor while preserving all attributes of the same object. Maybe a method designed for sorting could have been better. Just that it won't fit again into a on-line kind of requirement.

Comment: @nullpointer yes, but during collection pipeline, we should not mute object but let them be unmutable because of the thread safety of solution. I have preassumed that students could be a parallel stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few one liner examples that should get you started, using java streams.

```
List<String> sorted = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Input1", "Input2", "Etc")).stream().sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));


List<String> sorted = json.stream().sorted((a, b) -> a.compareTo(b));


List<String> sorted = json.stream().sorted();
```

Here is how to sort all lists inside of a list, so you can refactor now to make it a one liner

```
void method() {
    sort(list);
}

void sort(List list) {
    if (list.size() == 0)
        return;

    list.stream().sorted();
    for (Object o : list)
        if (o instanceof List)
            sorted((List) o);
}
```

Here are some references to java streams:

API Docs:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

Examples:

https://stackify.com/streams-guide-java-8/

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stream-in-java/

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```
List<Student> result = new ArrayList<>();
studentList.stream()
           .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Student::getRollNo))
           .map(student -> {
                student.getSubjects().sort(Comparator.nullsLast(Comparator.comparing(Subjects::getSubjectCode)));
                return student;
            }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @AAnuj Kumar Son have you seen this?

Comment: This is a bad solution - in such case you can easily avoid muting collection outside collection pipeline. As a rule of thumb you should avoid such constructs because of thread safety

Comment: @MichałMarcinkowski IMO it's better than create new object and waste time and resources! what do you think? anyway I updated my answer!

Comment: But it is insecure from a thread safety perspective, what if two threads try to modify the list in exactly the same time? To ensure that modifying outside collection will not break the program you have to synchronize list and operating on the synchronized list is in my opinion much more resource consuming than creating new List.